# what is better insert values in an array and then sorting or inserting while maintaining sorted order?

Tags: c++, optimization

In C++, which is faster?

1. Adding elements in an array, and then sorting it using radix sort.
2. Merge sort or inserting them while maintaining the order by simply shifting higher elements to higher indexes, thus making space for inserting an element.

I'n my case the size of the array is maximum 100.

Comment: With only 100 elements, it won't matter.

Comment: I always thought sorting at the end is better than mantaining the set ordered. Although what @Yuushi said is true.

Comment: If the only operation you need to perform on your array is 'peek/pop largest element', then a binary heap (as used to implement the data structure called Priority Queue) is very quick to maintain in 'sorted' order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the size of 100 elements, the process is so quick that you won't even recognise any differences.

So which ever way you want.

However, if you are looking at a larger number of items in an array, I would say the second option is faster. Because radix sort uses a secondary buffer to store partial sorting results. This increase the memory required for this algorithm. It makes a big different when dealing with big number of elements.